# Running bash script with at command (scheduled script) not working

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, google-chrome-os, chromebook

My scheduled script isn't working this is what I've tried:
I have a b.sh file with the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "hello, $USER"
```

I want to try using the "at" command for a scheduled send in 1 minute as follows `echo b.sh | at now + 1 minute`
but nothing is executing anywhere...

I checked the queue with `atq` first and confirmed it was waiting for the next minute to execute, but one minute later, nothing was happening anywhere.

Is it executing somewhere and I'm not looking in the right place? I was under the impression it should execute in the terminal before my eyes...

Comment: `at` will run your script in its own new subshell. An `echo` command run by `at` will not be visible in any terminal. If you want to test to see if your `atd` is working, you could try something like `touch ~/test.txt`

Comment: What do you expect the command `hello, $USER` to do?

Comment: no, it will not execute in the terminal before your eyes. if sendmail is configured correctly you'll be sent an email with the output, otherwise, you may never know what happened. what you might want to do is something like `echo "foo" > /tmp/somefile`.  maybe you are wanting something like `sleep 60; ./b.sh`

Comment: `at` jobs run in the background, not attached to any terminal. Also, that should probably be `./b.sh`, since the current directory is unlikely to be an an `at` job's `PATH` (note that `at` jobs environments may be different from your interactive shell environment in a number of ways).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the process used with `at` command is executed by `atd` daemon.

`atd` daemon is not attached to your terminal.

But, if you want to print messages, you have two solutions:

1. Redirect your outputs to a file like this at the beginning of your script :

```sh
exec > /path/to/my_log/file.log
exec 2>&1
```

2. Write on the TTY of your bash:

Execute your `at` command like this:

```sh
echo "FATHER_TTY=$(tty) ./b.sh" | at now + 1 minute
```

And, the content of your `./b.sh` script:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
exec > "${FATHER_TTY}"
exec 2>&1
echo "hello, $USER"
```